# Arch Linux: No Sound

Tags: arch-linux, audio

I have just clean installed Arch Linux on my laptop, and there is no sound whatsoever. I can't raise the volume, and in settings it displays the only output as "Dummy Output". Is my driver not loaded in correctly, and if so, how do I load it?

Here is the output of `asoundconf list`:

```
Names of available sound cards:
PCH
chtrt5650
```

Here is the output of `cat /dev/asound/cards`:

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1314000 irq 315
 1 [chtrt5650      ]: chtrt5650 - chtrt5650
```

I have tried unmuting the sound (`amixer sset Master unmute`) with no success:

```
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0
```

Repeated slightly differently (`amixer -c1 sset Master unmute`) but it gives same output:

```
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0
```

At this point I really am lost, just stuck with a "Dummy Output" which does nothing. Any help would be appreciated, and I will edit the question with any more command outputs necessary.

**EDIT:** I have used Ubuntu, Debian, Pop!_OS and others on my laptop and sound works perfectly with them. My sound card is Intel (not sure of the exact model). I have all `pulseaudio` and `alsa` optional dependencies installed, and I have even tried `pulseaudio --start` which doesn't work. I am booted via UEFI if that helps. Not sure what other info I can provide...

Comment: Did you read Pulseaudio archwiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio) page?

Comment: @mattia.b89 Yes I read this but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: please provide more info: what sound related package did you installed? are you using pulseaudio? have you ever tried other distros on your laptop? did the sound work?